# Server raid doesn't boot in the morning

Tags: raid, boot, hp-proliant, raid-controller

We have a HP Proliant ML350 G6 with integrated sas raid controller. Since 3 days the server starts up in the morning without this raid. All othe HDDs / SDDs are ok.

We did install the ServicePack 2014.09, replaced the mainboard-battery and removed the raid battery (looked ugly, like it could be damaged, new one will be inserted when arrived).

There is an post error 1796, HP says "

1796-Drive Array – Array Accelerator Not Responding... 
...Array Accelerator is temporarily disabled." at this page: http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01702138

After reboot the server is fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the problem?

Comment: the server is used as baremetal Xen Virtualisation server. Important VMs are missing when the raid isn't booted. I would like to know what I could check or change, so that the server boots every time with the raid.

Answer (score 0):

The battery attached to the RAID controller's cache module allows the write cache (array accelerator) to work. Without the battery, the array accelerator is disabled.

The ML350 G6 server was sold from 2009-2012, and HP RAID batteries last 3-5 years. So your old battery may have died. Just replace it with a new battery and you should be fine.

Comment: I did buy a new battery and wait for delivery. So you think that the raid boot problems could be caused by the faulty / missing battery?

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this problem was a faulty hdd. It did failed yesterday. I did remove the faulty hdd and waited till the raid was rebuilded. The server did boot correct this morning.

How can I detect the health state of hp raid disks?